# SSL not working on wordpress contactpage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I'm facing a strange issue here.
One of my clients website is using SSL.
Every page except the contact page, is running on a secure connection (green lock icon in browser).

How do I solve this issue?

Things Ive done:

For starters I did this:
in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

And of course in wp-config.php :

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true); 
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
```

However this did not solve the issue, so I tried this in functions.php

```
function G_force_ssl( $force_ssl, $post_id = 0, $url = '' ) {

    // 18918 is the page ID of the contactpage
    $list_of_post_page = array(18918);

    if ( in_array( $post_id, $list_of_post_page ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return $force_ssl;
}
add_filter('force_ssl' , 'G_force_ssl', 10, 3);
```

The theme developer suggested this:

```
function replace_http( $original ) {
    // use preg_replace() to replace http:// with https://
    $output = preg_replace( "^http:", "https:", $original );
    return $output;
}

add_filter( 'template_url', 'replace_http' );
```

This also didn't work.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does the URL for the contact page say https:// and just not display the green lock icon (which may be due to mixed content served via HTTP -- use F12/ Developers tools to see any warnings) or is the issue that the contact page uses HTTP when the rest of the site uses HTTPS?

Comment: It says https but doesn't display the lock. The lock appears only for 2 seconds and disappears again. Check out: goo.gl/f3xf2T

Comment: Here's the culprit (seen by looking at the Console log under Developer's tools): Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.gstalt.nl/contact/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.gstalt.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/pin1.png'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Of courseeeee, I completely forgot the fact, we were using a custom pin. Thank you.